# Renaming files with unnecessary zeros in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, rename, batch-processing

I've been looking into batch renaming files with Powershell and I've made some good progress. To put it simply I'm looking to remove all extra zeros from the beginning of my files. So far I have a folder of images named as such:

```
0001_random_name.jpg
0002_random_name.jpg
0003_random_name.jpg
```

All the way up to 900~. I created a Powershell script that takes the first four characters and adds the .jpg extension back. Here is that script:

```
Get-ChildItem 'G:\InvaluableNumbered' | rename-item -newname { $_.name.substring(0,4) + ".jpg" }
```

This renames the files to

```
0001.jpg
0002.jpg
0003.jpg
```

For this project I need to name them

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

All the way up to 968.jpg. Is there any way I can use the script that I wrote and then have another command that removes all 0s up to where it hits the first number greater than zero?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi @PetSerAl , thank you for the quick response! I couldn't imagine it was that simple, where would I put that in the code I have?

Comment: After value, you want to trim: `$_.name.substring(0,4).TrimStart('0')`.

Comment: That did exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TrimStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) string method to achieve desired result:

```
$_.name.substring(0,4).TrimStart('0')
```

Other possibility could be cast value to `[int]` and then back to `[string]`:

```
[string][int]$_.name.substring(0,4)
```